# Hibernate select query: only want to know existence

Tags: performance, hibernate, hql

I need only the existence information of a record. I don't need the actual count. If there is a row (record) respect to the "`where`" condition, I will know that it exists.

If I write

```
select count(m) from MyEntity m where m.someProperty=1
```

it will count all the records and if there are many records, it may take long time and it will give me the information which I don't need actually.

How do I get the existence of a records with Hibernate HQL?

Comment: Maybe you need setMaxResults(1): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28498378/706695

Comment: @HRgiger thank you, also this one looked well for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29745642/169534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one as best for me:

```
public Boolean existsOrNot (DTOAny i) {
    Query q = getSession().             
    createQuery("select 1 from DTOAny t where t.key = :key");
        q.setString("key", i.getKey() );
    return (q.uniqueResult() != null);
}
```

from:
[HQL Query to check whether table has data or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745464/hql-query-to-check-whether-table-has-data-or-not)